# how to combine data of two list views

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have two list views

```
List1= {a, b, c, d, e, x, f, g, h, i, j, k} and

List2= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

and i want to put list in format like

[image]

and i have two spinners. Suppose in spinner first i choose item "c" and in spinner second i choose item "6" and after that if i click on button show then it should shows listview which will show data like

```
List3={c, d, e, x, 4, 5, 6}
```

and in same way if choose another two items like "h" and "2" then it should show list like

{2, 3, x, f, g, h}

how to achieve this.

Comment: why do you count from the beginning of each axis (and use letters)? wouldn't it be easier to count from the center (your x point) using positive and negative values and a flag to distinguish the axes? later on you could easily translate these values to letters if you wish.

Comment: if you can show me some examples. i am not getting it

Comment: why is it, that the 1st is like letters x numbers and the 2nd is like numbers x letters? Or is it important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I assume that you defined List1, List2 and List3 as members of the "List< String >" class, and that you can make a ListView if List3 is ready.
If the user clicks on the `i`th  letter and the `j`th number then:

```
List3.clear();
int index = (List1.size() - 1) / 2; //index of 'x'
while (i<>index) {
   List3.add(List1.get(i));
   if (i>index) { i--; } else { i++; };
}
i = (List2.size() - 1) / 2; //index of 'x'
index = j;
while (i<>index) {
   List3.add(List2.get(i));
   if (i>index) { i--; } else { i++; };
}
//construct your ListView here using data of List3
```

I hope this was what you wanted to do and I didn't misunderstood you.. 
And hope this helps...

Comment: hey EMarci thanks for your response. I ll implement it and ll let you know